# Heroku, Selenium python, discord bot

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, discord.py

I'm sorry for my bad english.
I wrote a python discord bot that has a command that uses selenium (google chromedriver). Everything works fine on my computer. But when I put the bot on Heroku hosting, then EXACTLY on Heroku I get the following error:

> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287421+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287421+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287441+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287471+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287471+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287490+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287490+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287508+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287508+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> 2022-06-02T09:32:56.287535+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Maybe I didn't install some library? Or, this hosting does not have chromedriver? Everything works great on my computer. Help me please!

Comment: I guess you define your driver in an if block and the condition doesn't return true on heroku for some reason. Can't really see your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include the code for that command.